# How do I run 3 sequential methods in independent fashion in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a scenario where I have an Input X that is given to function A, then to function B and then to function C and finally gives an output Y.

This process happens in sequence hence is slow. I am trying to build this in Python.

Can you guide me on what I should use so that method A, B and C can run independently such that as soon as method A finishes processing 1 item it dispatches it to B and starts processing the next item without waiting for method B and C to finish it's work.

I am new to programming and have limited knowledge in multithreading & concurrency so any help would be awesome.

Comment: Multiprocessing

Comment: It depends on what type of processes are A, B, and C : I/O bound vs CPU bound.
And we need to know more about both the data and the process if you want more than general advice.

Comment: Sounds like a pipeline. A waits for input, does its thing, puts something into a blocking queue. B waits on the queue, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to rebuild your function sequence in combination with multithreading.

Here is what ive come up with:

```
import threading
import time

# Your functions
def functionA(num):
    res = num + 1
    time.sleep(2)
    functionB(res)

def functionB(num):
    res = num * 2
    time.sleep(2)
    functionC(res)

def functionC(num):
    res = num - 5
    time.sleep(2)
    print(res)

thread_counter = 0
while True:
    inp = int(input("Enter Number: "))

    if inp == 0: # When input is 0 it stops input
        break

    # Thread creation and starting
    globals()[f"Thread{thread_counter}"] = threading.Thread(target=functionA, args=(inp,))
    globals()[f"Thread{thread_counter}"].start()

    thread_counter += 1
```

So we are creating a new Thread for every input that runs the `functionA` and this function gives the result to `functionB` and so on. Theoretically you can have unlimited inputs. Note: `globals()` might be a bad way for creating variables.

The Output for the inputs 5 and 7 would look like this:

```
Enter Number: 5
Enter Number: 7
Enter Number: 0
7
11
```

I've put the 0 as an exit value so you can break the while loop. A visualization would be look like this:

[image: Multithreading Image]